# My Python code is not printing the result after completion in my def statement. What is the issue?

Tags: python

I want to have my code print a certain string, showing the cost of the user's liability insurance depending on what they choose. Here is the code:

```
print("Use this program to estimate your liability.")


def main():
    user_name = get_user_name()
    user_age = get_age()
    violation = get_violations()
    risk_code(violation, user_age, user_name)


# Input#

# Def for name

def get_user_name():
    user_name = input("What is your name?")
    return user_name


# Def for age
def get_age():
    user_age = int(input("What is your age?"))
    if user_age < 16 or user_age > 105:
        print("Invalid entry, try again.")
        get_age()
    return user_age
    

# Def for traffic violations (tickets.)
def get_violations():
    violation = input("How many traffic violations (tickets) do you have?")
    return violation


# Process#
def risk_code(violation, age, user_age):
    if violation == 0 and age >= 25:
        risk = "None"
        cost = int(275)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 0 and age <= 25:
        risk = "None"
        cost = int(325)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 1 and age >= 25:
        risk = "Low"
        cost = int(315)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 1 and age <= 25:
        risk = "Low"
        cost = int(380)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 2 and age >= 25:
        risk = "Moderate"
        cost = int(365)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 2 and age <= 25:
        risk = "Moderate"
        cost = int(405)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 3 and age >= 25:
        risk = "Moderate"
        cost = int(390)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 3 and age <= 25:
        risk = "Moderate"
        cost = int(450)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 4 and age >= 25:
        risk = "High"
        cost = int(410)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
    elif violation == 4 and age <= 25:
        risk = "High"
        cost = int(480)
        print(user_name, " as a ", risk, " driver, your insurance will cost $", cost)
main()
```

My main issue is that the code does not actually print. Am I missing something fundamental? Shouldn't they print upon execution of the code? Or is there an easier way to simplify this? Thank you!

Comment: Assuming `violations` is supposed to be a number (according to the prompt), you forgot to convert to an `int`...

Comment: Firstly for your problem. Yes it should print, but none of your if statements is True since you get a String from get_violations(). Cast it just like in your get_age() function. Secondly: Check your get_age() functions if statement, there you call your get_age function recursively but that wont work until you return the result. It should be `return get_age()`

Comment: In addition to the other observations, your `get_age()` function doesn't return the result of the recursive call, so when you input an invalid age the function will ask for a valid age but return the invalid age entered first.

Comment: Repeating the identical `print()` statement in each branch isn't necessary, put it below all the elifs.

Comment: ...and this should probably be moved to Code Review...

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner This question would be off-topic on Code Review as it does not work as intended. In the future please link to the help center and use wording that shows the post may be off-topic when recommending Code Review. Take, "This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there."

Comment: For age 25, your cases are not well determined. The first case will match, but the code is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

There's no unconditional print in your code so if no condition is met, nothing will show up. You need to better debug your code or at least introduce `else` to catch  such case.

Comment: Hey! Went by what you said. I am getting a "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'" although I cannot find a floating number within my code.

Answer (score 1):

First, put your `def main():` function definition on the bottom of the script (convention) and then, below that, `print` on the same indent level as the call to `main()`

```
print("Use this program to estimate your liability.")
main()
```

Second, include `else` statements whenever you say `if` or `elif`.

```
if user_age < 16 or user_age > 105:
   print("Invalid entry, try again.")
   get_age()
else:
   print('user age criteria not me")
```

do that everywhere & check what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the real problem here... There is no problem with the first `print` statement being above everything...